# Under-development mobile app security

Tags: android

I am developing mobile web apps, and one difficulty of this is testing the apps on my phone.  How do I keep others from accessing the alpha test while still being able to access the app from my own phone so I can write and test the app without having to worry about people stealing my idea before Release Day?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy your alpha .apk on a webserver in a password protected directory. The alpha testers get the link,username and password to the apk. The android devices must be configured allow app installations from untrusted sources.

Deluxe Version:
Within the app add a feature that checks for new versions in that protected directory and downloads/installs them automatically, so you and your testers don't have to do this manually each time a new build is released.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to enable the "Debugging mode" in the settings of your device. Secondly, you should plug your phone to your PC per USB. Finally, you can upload your .apk directly from eclipse to the device and test it on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alpha test with actual users then you will have to create some sort of provisioning scheme.  You can give each user a key - when they type it in on initial install, it polls your server to see if the key has been used before.  Your app should only activate if the key is unused at that point.

If you just want to test on your own phone, then upload the APK yourself - do not go through the Android Market or any other app market.